# guard statement inconsistencies

Tags: swift, swift2, guard-statement

// Doing let first followed by a bool check in guard statement results in compilation error

```
   self.action = {  [weak self] in
      guard let `self` = self, data.isJSON() else { return }
```

// Doing bool check first and then let works

```
  self.action = {  [weak self] in
     guard data.isJSON(), let `self` = self else { return }
```

The two statements above seem equivalent to me.  Why will it not work in the first case?

Answer (score 4):

#### Re-constructing your question into a minimal, complete and verifiable example

First of all note that it would be preferable if your question contained a [minimal, complete and verifiable example (mvce)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which, in its current form, it does not:

- the closure list is irrelevant and only confusing here
- the unknown `self` (... no context) is, likewise, only confusing and of no relevance to this question

Instead, a mvce of your question could've bee constructed along the lines of:

```
func foo(bar: Int?) {
    // 1. why does this cause a compile time error?
    guard let baz = bar, true else { return }

    // 2. whereas this does not?
    guard true, let bax = bar else { return }
}
```

The answer below will discuss this mvce, rather than the obscured example in the original question. Finally note also that the `guard`/`guard let` statement is not entirely relevant (unique) w.r.t. the core of the question, as we see the same behaviour for `if`/`if let` statements. The answer below will use `guard` statements.

---

#### Now, can we redeem the compile time error in 1. above? And, are these two statements really equivalent?

The compile time error for the 1st `guard` statement in the function `foo(...)` above is quite telling

> Boolean condition requires `where` *to separate it from variable binding*.
>
> Fix it: replace `,` with `where`

This is also stated in the [Language Guide - The Basics - Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> You can include multiple optional bindings in a single `if` statement
>   *and use a `where` clause to check for a `Boolean` condition*. If any of the values in the optional bindings are `nil` or the `where` clause
>   evaluates to `false`, the whole optional binding is considered
>   unsuccessful.

Hence, if we want to use a condition-clause *after* optional binding in an `guard` or `if` statement, you need to use a `where` clause to separate the condition-clause from the preceding optional binding.

```
func foo(bar: Int?) {
    // 1. ok, compiles
    guard let baz = bar where true else { return }

    /* 2. or, include a conditional-clause prior to the
          optional binding, but is this really equivalent..? */
    guard true, let bax = bar else { return }
}
```

These two are, however, not really equivalent;

- statement 2. above allows us to short-circuit the `guard` statement in case the initial conditional-clause turns out to be `false` (then not proceeding to the optional binding, but rather directly into the `else` block of the `guard` statement)
- whereas 1. above allows the reverse: check the conditional-clause only if the optional binding succeeds.

There are naturally cases in which we would prefer one over the other, e.g. if the conditional-clause contains some really heavy calculations, we might not want to execute these unless we're certain that the optional binding succeeds

```
let heavyStuff: () -> Bool = { print("foo"); /* ... */ return true }

func foo(bar: Int?) {
    /* 1. call the heavyStuff boolean construct only if
          the optional binding succeeds */
    guard let baz = bar where heavyStuff() else { return }

    /* 2. possibly unnesessarily perform heavy boolean
          stuff prior to failing the optional binding */
    guard heavyStuff(), let bax = bar else { return }
}
```

A less contrived example is if we want to use a successfully binded variable in (here: as an argument) in the conditional-clause that follows

```
let integerStuff: (Int) -> Bool = { _ in /* ... */ return true }

func foo(bar: Int?) {
    /* 1. call the integerStuff boolean construct only if
          the optional binding succeeds, using the binded
          immutable as closure argument */
    guard let baz = bar where integerStuff(baz) else { return }

    /* 2. ... not really any good alternatives for such 
          flow if using this alternative */
    guard integerStuff(baz ?? 0), let bax = bar else { return }
}
```

Finally note that, *technically*, if you really want to separate an initial optional binding with a following conditional-clause, you could use dummy `case let` (non-optional always-succeeding variable binding/assignment) statement coupled with a `where` keyword for your conditional-clause

```
let checkThis: () -> Bool = { /* ... */ return true }

func foo(bar: Int?) {
    // ...
    guard let baz = bar, case let _ = () where checkThis() else { return }
}
```

This is, however, just to show this technicality; in practice, just use a `where` clause.